# How to position components side by side, without them moving around

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to put 2 components side by side but I would like one of components to be on the right of the other component without the other component being reorientated.
Example:
[image]

Here, after adding a button component to the side of the "Function" heading, the "Function" heading gets pushed to the left. However, I would like the "Function" heading to be in the middle and the "TEST" at the right. As much as possible, I'd like to avoid absolute positions.

````
<h4 align="right" style={{display: "inline-block"}}>Function</h4><Button sx={{float: "right"}}>Test</Button>```
This is my current code but I'm unsure what I can do. Thanks in advance!
````

Comment: Although every web developer needs to learn the "fundamentals" of HTML5 and CSS (and every ReactJS developer is a "web developer")... I'd strongly urge you to consider adopting a framework like BootStrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me, but I believe you should read about flex layout CSS property.

All possible solutions of your question

```css
.flex0 {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex1 {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex2 {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex0">
<h4 align="right" style={{display: "inline-block"}}>Function</h4><Button sx={{float: "right"}}>Test</Button>
</div>


<div class="flex1">
<h4 align="right" style={{display: "inline-block"}}>Function</h4><Button sx={{float: "right"}}>Test</Button>
</div>


<div class="flex2">
<h4>Function</h4><Button>Test</Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.flex-child:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-child magenta">
    Flex Column 1
  </div>

  <div class="flex-child green">
    Flex Column 2
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. But first you must understand why this misalignment happens when you use `float`.

Without `float` on button you can see it perfectly aligns to the heading with `inline-block`; but as soon as you introduce the float, it detaches the button as pushes it on the right side of the screen on the top corner of the block line. (image attached)

[image: button w/o float]

[image: button with float]

This happened because the heading tags, by default, have margins.

[image: heading margins]

So to align them properly,

1st thing you can do is to provide the `float` button a similar margin as that of the heading.

```
    <div>
      <h4 style='display: inline-block;'>Function</h4>
      <Button style='float: right; width: 50px; height: 30px; margin: 1.33em'>Test</Button>
    </div>
```

2nd:
Wrap them in a div and use a `grid` with `align-items: center`

```
<div style='display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; align-items: center;'>
    <h4 style='display: inline-block;'>Function</h4>
    <Button style='margin-left: 85%; width: 50px; height: 30px;'>Test</Button>
</div>
```

3rd
going the usual way, introduce left margin to the button in % (or vice-versa) i.e without `float`

```
<div>
    <h4 style='display: inline-block;'>Function</h4>
    <Button style='margin-left: 75%;'>Test</Button>
</div>
<div>
    <h4 style='display: inline-block; margin-right: 85%;'>Function</h4>
    <Button style=''>Test</Button>
</div>
```

Other options:

Utilise flex containers as suggested by other answers.